# Compare two values and get a third

Tags: excel, formula

I am having difficulty getting this to work.  I have three columns, and two of which have duplicate values in them (which is a good thing).  I need to take column 1 and compare it to column 2.  If the value in column 1 is in column 2 then get the value in column 3. Example:

```
Hello | Test   | 123
Test  | Object | 321
Dog   | Cat    | 456
Cat   | Animal | 654
```

(I know that is a bit confusing so..) Seeing as there is Test and Cat in both column 1 and 2 then I would get the values 123 and 456.

Anyone know of a formula to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, something like this should do the trick:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B1,$A$1:$A$4,0)),"",C1)
```

The `$A$1:$A$4` would be the range of the column to check.

Check to see if there is a match for the value in the other column.

If so, get the value listed in column C.

You would drag the formula down column D and it would list values like this:

[image: Picture]

Comment: Thank you!  That worked perfectly how I wanted it.  Big help!